Issue with Dockerized pgAdmin 4: passfile : fe_sendauth: no password supplied
I'm trying to set up pgAdmin 4 using the following Dockerfile:
FROM dpage/pgadmin4 AS custom-pgadmin

COPY <<-"EOT" /pgadmin4/servers.json
{
    "Servers": {
      "1": {
        "Name": "Postgres Prefect",
        "Group": "Servers",
        "Host": "database",
        "Port": 5432,
        "Username": "postgres",
        "MaintenanceDB": "prefect",
        "SSLMode": "prefer",
        "PassFile": "/pgadmin4/pgpass"
      }
    }
}
EOT

COPY <<-"EOT" /pgadmin4/pgpass
database:5432:prefect:postgres:postgres
EOT

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/entrypoint.sh"]

What works:

The database appears in the web UI under Properties > Parameters:
Password file - passfile - /pgadmin4/pgpass


After manually entering postgres in the password prompt modal, the connection works perfectly.

Issue:
When I click on the server in pgAdmin, I get the following error:
connection failed: connection to server at "172.21.0.8", port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

pgAdmin seems to ignore the credentials from /pgadmin4/pgpass and prompts for a password.
What I've Tried:

The file /pgadmin4/pgpass exists and looks correct:
database:5432:prefect:postgres:postgres


I confirmed that the path /pgadmin4/pgpass matches the PassFile value in the servers.json.

Question:
Does anyone know why pgAdmin might not be picking up the password file? Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.
